# Recursive length function implementation in a linked-list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am implementing a linked-list, and one of the function asks for the number of nodes in the linked list. However, as the requirement says it needs to be done recursively.

Here is my implementation so far.

```
class  LList {
    public:
       bool isEmpty() const;
       void cons(int x);
       int length() const;
    private:
       struct Node {
          int item;
          Node* next;
       };
       Node* head;
}

bool LList::isEmpty() const{
   if(head == nullptr)
       return true;
   else
      return false;
}
void LList::cons(int x){
   Node* temp = new Node;
   temp->item = x;
   temp->next = head;
   head = temp;
}
```

I can only do this iteratively, but couldn't make the recursion work.

```
int LList::length(Node* head) const{
    Node* temp = head;
    if (temp == nullptr) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + length(temp->next);
}

int LList::length() const {
    return length(head);
}
```

I tried to use a helper function to do the job, but it's saying declaration is incompatible with `int LList::length() const`

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-length-of-a-linked-list-iterative-and-recursive/) would help.

Comment: but this does not have any parameters. And i really don't know how to overload this function properly.

Comment: Recursion should not go back to the start every time, so `Node* temp = head;` is extremely problematic.consider making a helper function that takes a `Node *` as a parameter.Can you add a `private` function to the class that can be called from `length`?

Comment: What if head is null? Won't it crash?   What you want is to add 1 when node->next is not null then call node length.   Of course in the real work you'd not use recursion for this. You'd maintain a length variable when adding or removing nodes in LList.

Comment: Why not using the same return type for length() as the size() functions of the STL containers? And why naming it length(), when C++ programmers are used to size()? Don't repeat the errors the Qt implementors made. Also why not empty() instead of isEmpty()...

Comment: Changing your question in such a way that answers (and comments) are invalidated is not a nice thing to do. If you have further questions based on your answers, don't edit your question but post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You are recursing the wrong place: You only have a single `LList`, so there is nothing to recurse on there. What you want to do instead is to recurse on the `Node` objects.

Keep your `int LList::length() const` function, but all it has to do is check if `head` is `nullptr` and then call the new recursive function that you are going to make: `int LList::Node::length() const`. This one then recurses through the `next` pointers of your `Node` objects and counts them.

Comment: @molbdnilo OP has changed his code since I wrote my answer. It is looking much better now, which (ironically) makes my answer look worse. :)

Comment: @Frodyne I see. This answer made a whole lot of sense with the original question.